# loop prepare statements, what needs to be repeated?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm using statements to protect against sql injections... My question is what do i need to repeat when looping multiple queries?

If you look at the second query, im not sure if the prepare statement needs to be insde the foreach loop

Something wrong with this summary code?

open database connection

```
// connect to database   
$conn = connect('r');
```

launch first query

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE xxx = ?";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $albumid);
$stmt->bind_result(..., ...);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

if ($num_rows  > 0) {
   loop results...
}

$stmt->free_result();
```

second query with repeats:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE xxx = ?";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql); ///??????? inside or outside foreach loop ?????

foreach (... as $key => ...) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $key);
    $stmt->bind_result(...);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    if ($num_rows  > 0) {
       loop results...
    }

   $stmt->free_result();
}
```

close database

```
// close database
$conn->close();
```

Comment: prepare and bind_* can be and should be outside of the loop.

Comment: ok, thanks. im guessin that '$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();' doesnt need to be call twice, right? i dont need to initialize a statement twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to prepare the query multiple times. Just bind the parameters and execute it multiple times.

From the PHP Manual:

> For a query that you need to issue multiple times, you will realize
>   better performance if you prepare a PDOStatement object using
>   PDO::prepare() and issue the statement with multiple calls to
>   PDOStatement::execute().

Hope this helps.